# Im getting the message "resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/html"

Tags: javascript, ajax, mime-types

My js files are not getting loaded and Im getting the message "resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/html".May I know how I can solve this issue.

Thanks,
Balaji

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds more like a server issue than a javascript issue.

It seems rather odd that any server would not have a MIME type set for .js files.
Do the files have a different extension?

Perhaps your HTML needs to be modified to be more specific?

`<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="functions.js"></script>`

You'll have to provide a bit more information to get a more specific answer to your question.

Comment: Hi Travis, thank you for your reply,this is how my js files are specified   <script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/clientlibs/foundation/jquery.js"></script> Please let me know if I need to specify some other details

Comment: That should be enough in the HTML to get it into the browser.

Let's start with some basics:
- Is that the script that is causing the error, or are you loading a script dynamically via ajax?
- Does it work in other browsers?
- Have you checked the response headers from the server? What did it say?

Answer (score 1):

As travis already said it is probably because of the server misconfiguration.

Assuming the full URL to your js file is $SCRIPT_URL you can run any of the following commands in the console to figure out the content type your server server your js file with:

```
$ wget -O /dev/null --server-response $SCRIPT_URL 2>&1 | grep -i content-type
$ curl --include --silent $SCRIPT_URL | grep -i content-type
```

If you get something like `Content-Type: application/x-javascript` the server is ok.

But I suppose your output would be something like `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` that means your server config needs to be fixed. That fix is server dependent and you should provide more info, such as what server do you use so that we could help you.

Kudos to travis.